# Tell excel to look at previous cell to current I array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I’m currently using an i array to get excel to run through several lines.

What I need to do is write some vba that tells excel to compare the current cell to the previous cell.

So if (“a” & i) is equal to a22 I need to compare the value to the value in a21

I’ve tried

```
If range(“a” & i) = range(“a” & i)-1 then

If range(“a” & i) = range(“a” & i).offset(-1, 0) then
```

But none of these worked. Any help much appreciated

Comment: The second one will work if you use normal quotes rather than curly ones. In the first the -1 needs to be inside the brackets. Btw saying they don't work is not a helpful description of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your i start i=0 then `.offset(-1, 0) then` do error because not exist row 0.
Regardless of the condition of the second if, by i = 0 "offset (-1,0)", of the error.
if you need to start on line 1, it is necessary not to let the code execute "offset (-1,0)" then, use "If (i <> 1) Then" to work around the error.
Look like this: Good Luck.

```
For i = 1 To 10
range("A" & i).Select

If range("A" & i) = range("A" & i) - 1 Then Stop

If (i <> 1) Then
    If range("A" & i) = range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 0) Then Stop
End If
Next i
```